# Problem with get_absolute_url based on entry type

Tags: python, django, django-models

I have one model for different types of entries:

```
POST = 1
PAGE = 2
ARTICLE = 3
ENTRY_TYPE = (
    (POST, "Blog Post"),
    (PAGE, "Page"),
    (ARTICLE, "Article"),
)

entry_type = models.IntegerField(choices=ENTRY_TYPE, default=POST)
```

And function to find out absolute url for different types of entries based on it type:

```
def get_absolute_url(self):        
    if self.PAGE:
        return '/%s/' % (self.slug)
    elif self.ARTICLE:
        return '/article/%s/' % (self.slug)
    elif self.POST:
        return '/blog/%s/' % (self.slug)
```

But this function doesn't work, and i can't find out, why. For all types of entries function return 'PAGE' url.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be looking at the value of `self.entry_type`, e.g.:

```
if self.entry_type == self.PAGE:
    return '/%s/' % (self.slug)
```

Comment: Awwww.. I tried to figure out an hour and everything was so simple. Thank you!